# One-by-one queue reading in WAS9

Tags: java, jms, ejb, websphere

Run into problems. How to make MDB read messages from the queue one at a time instead of several at the same time. That is, until 1 message completely passes through the MDB+EJB module, the new message was not read by MDB. The application is deployed on WebSphere 9, maybe there you can configure it in this way?

Comment: A bit of code might help us understand what you are currently trying to do and what needs to be changed so it starts working as intended? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straight forward, look here for details [JMS activation specification Settings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/SIBJMSActivationSpec_DetailForm.html). You just need to configure `Maximum concurrent MDB invocations per endpoint` for activation specification for your MDB to `1`.